# Invisible graphics with dynamic text in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, overlays

I want to use two different options for *setbeamercovered{}* in my presentation - *dynamic* for text and *invisible* for images. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  Go ahead and set out your code, beginning with `\begin{document}` and ending with `\end{document}` unless you are using plain tex in which case give us your code followed by `\bye` For an example see _What makes a good MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3350/90087

Answer (score 1):

Not really automatic, but this behaviour can be simulated with `\visible<.(1)->{}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{Theorem}
            Theorem Text Here
        \end{block}

        \vfill \pause 

        \begin{example} 
            \centering
            \visible<.(1)->{\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100bp}}
        \end{example}

        \vfill \pause

        \begin{block}{Corollary}
            Corollary text here
        \end{block}        

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]